# Can't access my wordpress wp-admin page after moving to new host

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently i transferred my wordpress website to a new hosting, and successfully transferred the file and the database. But I cant access the wp-admin page and  all other pages except the homepage, can you tell me what the problem is? my website is [arifmekina.net](http://arifmekina.net)

Comment: Change your home url and site url in database option table

Comment: Check mod_rewrite module is enabled or not .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp-admin can't access after moving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935715/wp-admin-cant-access-after-moving)

Comment: i already changed the home url and site url before, that is why the homepage works. But where I can find mod_rewrite.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935715/wp-admin-cant-access-after-moving

Comment: The above answer not have a solution for me.

Comment: Please check my web and give me an answer. my home page is arifmekina.net, click any of the link and you will get 404 Not Found Error

Comment: Oh Finally i got the answer by myself. I deleted the permalink option from the phpmyadmin and now it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

*You have go to the database...and in that there is table called 'wp_options' and in that there is two path will be changed.. two option value changed for the option name 'siteurl' and 'home' in this two option value changed to the 'http://www.arifmekina.net/'
so admin site open properly.. and then go to settings->permalinks and change settings once..so all things are worked properly*

Comment: I already changed that option. If I don't change that option the homepage itself doesn't work. is there any other solution.